# How to wait for the images to be loaded in React

Tags: reactjs, render

First of all I'm using ReactJS and I have the following **simplified** code snippet:

```
const Page = () => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    
    return (
        <Loading isLoading={isLoading} >
            <img src='https://example.com/img1' alt='image' />
            <img src='https://example.com/img2' alt='image' />
            <img src='https://example.com/img3' alt='image' />
            <img src='https://example.com/img4' alt='image' />
            <img src='https://example.com/img5' alt='image' />
            <img src='https://example.com/img6' alt='image' />
            <img src='https://example.com/img7' alt='image' />
        </Loading>
    )
}
```

**The problem:**
The images are displayed progressively, and one after one, which doesn't look good, like the following example:

[image]

**The solution that I'm searching for:**
I wanna show the `<Loading>` component by setting the variable `isLoading` to `true` ***after finishing the loading of the images***.
So when the page is opened, first the user sees a loading page, ***then after loading all the images***, the variable `isLoading` is set to false, to hide the `<Loading>`  component.

Comment: Are images coming from api?

Comment: @PriyenMehta yes

Comment: okay, Can you send all code? I am assuming you are using react.

Comment: @PriyenMehta thank you so much, as you can see in the attached GIF, the code is very complicated, I'll need to write more than 600 lines of code, which will be unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onLoad` attribute for your purpose.

```
const Page = () => {
    const [imageLoaded, setImageLoaded] = useState({});
    const handleLoadImage = (image) => {
        setImageLoaded(prev => {...prev, [image]: true});
    }
    const isLoading = useMemo(
        () => !(imagedLoaded.img1 && imagedLoaded.img2 && imagedLoaded.img3 && imagedLoaded.img4 && imagedLoaded.img5 && imagedLoaded.img6 && imagedLoaded.img7)
        , [imageLoaded] 
    )
    return (
        <Loading isLoading={isLoading} >
            <img onLoad={() => handleLoadImage("img1")} src={imgURL1} alt='image' />
            <img onLoad={() => handleLoadImage("img2")} src={imgURL2} alt='image' />
            <img onLoad={() => handleLoadImage("img3")} src={imgURL3} alt='image' />
            <img onLoad={() => handleLoadImage("img4")} src={imgURL4} alt='image' />
            <img onLoad={() => handleLoadImage("img5")} src={imgURL5} alt='image' />
            <img onLoad={() => handleLoadImage("img6")} src={imgURL6} alt='image' />
            <img onLoad={() => handleLoadImage("img7")} src={imgURL7} alt='image' />
        </Loading>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same solution, but I also wanted to be able to show a placeholder and something in case of an error.

In the end I settled for showing a placeholder image that would load almost instantly, and then replace it with the real deal once it is loaded:

```
import { useState } from 'react'

const LOADING_PREVIEW_IMAGE_PATH = '/pics/loading-preview-image.png'
const FAILED_LOAD_IMAGE_PATH = '/pics/failed-load-image.png'

function Image(realImageUrl) {
    const [isPreviewImageLoadedState, setPreviewImageLoaded] = 
        useState({image: LOADING_PREVIEW_IMAGE_PATH, error: false})

    return (
        <img src={isPreviewImageLoadedState.image}
            onLoad={() => {
                // Need to check if there was an error, or it will enter a loop where 
                // the empty image will oscillates between being loaded and the error image
                if (!isPreviewImageLoadedState.error) {
                    setPreviewImageLoaded({image: realImageUrl, error: false})
                }
            }}
            onError={() => setPreviewImageLoaded({image: FAILED_LOAD_IMAGE_PATH, error: true})} 
        />
    )
}
```

You may have to tweak a thing or two if you want to replace the image with different one (like setting the `key={}` to a Component up the chain). Just began learning ReactJS about 1 or 2 weeks ago, so take this suggestion with a pinch of salt.